# Does this function have a minimum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x, y, z) = xy - xz$$

My textbook asks to find the minimums of various different functions, and this is one of them. But I don't think this has a minimum. If $X=(x, y, z)$, then $f(tX)=t^2f(X)$, so if $f(X)$ is ever negative, the function will tend to $-\infty$ along the line generated by $X$. And $f(X)$ is negative at, for instance, $(1, -1, 0)$.

Am I missing something, or is the correct answer indeed just "there is no minimum" ?

Comment: Did you mean $f(x, y, z)$?

Comment: It obviously depends on the domain of the function, but if the domain is for all real $x,y,z$, yes you are correct.

Comment: @Amzoti Yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (corrected) function has no minimum, and your proof is correct.

Also, are you sure there isn't a domain on which this minimum is taken?  If it is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then we may take $x=1$ and let $y\to -\infty$.

Comment: There is no domain - I suppose the book just neglected to add "...or prove that it has no minimum". And I meant to say that $f$ is a function of $x, y$ a,d $z$. The proof still works after correction, right? $f(tX)$ is still a quadratic in $t$ with negative leading coefficient.